# Infinite redirection loop when using ws federation site and IIS url rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8, ws-federation

I cannot create rule for redirecting users on my ws-federation driven site when using improper browser: causes infinite loop... "Chrome" is now taken for simplicity, actually I will be testing against IE less than 9.

```
<rule name="UserAgentCheck" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="BrowserIsNotSupported" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="BrowserIsNotSupported" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Chrome" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="Isolate/BrowserIsNotSupported" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I sequentially receive:
301, 302, 307, 200 responses and everything starts over...

I even cannot figure out, if it's a logic error (match all against several conditions) or problem, related to using ws-federation. But anyway, I see BrowserIsNotSupported page, present as a part of wctx parameter and have no idea why it's not taken into consideration by QUERY_STRING condition.

```
http://localhost:14961/wsFederationSTS/Issue/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50207%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fIsolate%252fBrowserIsNotSupported&wct=2014-11-12T11%3a41%3a05Z
```

Comment: Now all of sudden Chrome and Firefox started working ok, but IE - not, it gives NotSupported page all the time, even though HTTP_USER_AGENT is Chrome or Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Little changes.
1) I have removed "AllowAnonymous" attribute from BrowserIsNotSupported method: let he be authenticated and then shown the page with message (no menu, no anything - just message and link to authentication portal)
2) Requests to the site which do matter are those that contain FedAuth cookie.
So modified solution for my problem is as follows:

```
<rule name="UserAgentCheck" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="BrowserIsNotSupported" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="BrowserIsNotSupported" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="FedAuth" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="MSIE 8.0|MSIE 7.0b|MSIE 7.0|MSIE 6.0b|MSIE 6.0|MSIE 5.5b1|MSIE 5.5|MSIE 5.0|MSIE 5.01|MSIE 4.0" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="Isolate/BrowserIsNotSupported" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```